# Interceptar y sincronizar al cambiar volumen del Audio en Android?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, audio-manager

Necesito detectar cuando hay un cambio de volumen del canal del Audio para así sincronizar el volumen establecido en una `SeekBar`

Al mostrar por ejemplo el dialogo donde se puede ajustar el volumen

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me gustaría detectar el cambio realizado, para así reflejar el cambio en tiempo real a la vista.

En mi layout tengo un `SeekBar`

```
sbVolumeBooster = (SeekBar) findViewById(R.id.seek_bar_volume);
```

Para obtener el rango máximo del volumen y asignar el tope a la `SeekBar`

```
sbVolumeBooster.setMax(audioManager.getStreamMaxVolume(streamType));
```

Intercepto el cambio que se puede realizar a la `SeekBar` para establecer el volumen.

```
sbVolumeBooster.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean b) {
        audioManager.setStreamVolume(streamType, progress, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

    }
});
```

**Lo que me falta**

Cuando se pulsa los botones físicos de subir o bajar volumen, aparece el dialogo por defecto de Android, muestra una barra para poder cambiar el volumen, pues me interesa obtener el volumen al que se ha dejado, para sincronizar el valor a la `SeekBar` de la vista de mi app.

Answer (score 0):

**Solucionado**

Se puede interceptar el cambio del volumen con un `ContentObserver` a las propiedades de configuración del sistema.

**Para registrar el observador**

```
mSettingsContentObserver = new SettingsContentObserver(new Handler());

getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().registerContentObserver(
        android.provider.Settings.System.CONTENT_URI, true,
        mSettingsContentObserver);
```

**Para quitar el observador**

```
getApplicationContext().getContentResolver().unregisterContentObserver(mSettingsContentObserver);
```

**El observador de cambio de configuración**

```
public class SettingsContentObserver extends ContentObserver {

    public SettingsContentObserver(Handler handler) {
        super(handler);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean deliverSelfNotifications() {
        return super.deliverSelfNotifications();
    }

    @Override
    public void onChange(boolean selfChange) {
        super.onChange(selfChange);
        Log.v(TAG, "Settings change detected " + selfChange);
        int currentVolume = audioManager.getStreamVolume(streamType);
        Log.d(TAG, "Volume now " + currentVolume);
        sbVolumeBooster.setProgress(currentVolume);
    }
}
```